# Return NotFound or BadRequest from browser request

Tags: asp.net-core, http

Simple question: What HTTP result do I return if my website (NOT an API call) receives an invalid request from a browser?

Suppose I have a web page that takes a URL argument, like this:

> https://example.com?id=123

If the argument is invalid then I can't display the requested page. My inclination is to return a `400 Bad Request`. But I have often seen code that returns a `404 Not Found`.

- If I return a `400 Bad Request` then the browser will simply display a blank page and the human user will probably stare at the screen for a while until it becomes obvious that something is terminally broken.
- If I return a `404 Not Found` then the browser will immediately display some sort of error message.

The only reason that my server should ever receive a request with an invalid argument *should* be either a malicious (or otherwise hand-crafted) call or a coding error in my own website that creates a bogus redirect. If the call is malicious then I really don't care if the caller stares at a blank screen. And if the caller is my own incorrect redirect then the user is stuck with a broken website and it kind of doesn't matter whether the user gets a weird "not found" error or just a blank screen.

Comment: If its website then `404` would be relevant and in case of Web API it should be `400`

Comment: Why? You are simply stating that you prefer the "usual code". Is there some reason not to return 400 in a website request? Or do people do it that way without really thinking about whether or not it is correct?

Comment: Well, if some one sent request with `https://example.com?id=`  without passing argument  it should be `400` because request `URL` and parameter is correct but argument is missing or invalid format. But if the  request comes with `https://example.com?id=123` or anything that doesn't exist it should be `404` as its valid but no relevant data founded. Hope I have explained my point. [You could have a look here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/SupportArticles-docs/blob/main/support/iis/http-status-code.md)

Comment: And there are RFC standard for that as well you also can [have a look here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-10.4.5)

Comment: So here's what I think you are saying: If a page request to my website detects an error with a URL argument, it should treat the request like an API request. (Let me emphasize that this is NOT a public API endpoint. Its a web page called with arguments generated by my code.) If the URL argument just happens to be intended to identify a resource managed by the website, and the resource doesn't exist, then a 404 error is appropriate. If it's some other unrecoverable URL argument error (the argument is missing, the wrong type, out of range, etc.) then a 400 error is appropriate. Correct?

Comment: Yes, I meant that, and this is the `RFC` and `W3C` standard actually, let me know if I can assist on anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a conversation with another SO user (see the comments on the original post) I am led to believe that the correct answer to my question is this:

If the URL arguments are missing or invalid, return an HTTP status code as though this was an API request.

- If a required URL argument is missing then return `400 Bad Request`.
- If a URL argument just happens to identify a resource that can't be found (for example, if the page displays the details of a widget whose ID is specified in a URL argument) then return `404 Not Found`. (This, of course, is confusing since the server returns `404 Not Found` if the URL specifies an endpoint that the server won't handle.)
- If a URL argument is otherwise invalid (wrong type, out of range, etc.) then return '400 Bad Request'